# What is the simplest way to display my (huge) php array in my jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

First of all, I'm noob...

I have a php array similar to this example :

```
`array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Car' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'field1' => 'blablabla',
            'field2' => 'blabla'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Car' => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'field1' => 'blablabla',
            'field2' => 'blabla'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Car' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'field1' => 'blablabla',
            'field2' => 'blabla'
        )
    )
)`
```

This array can contain a lot of rows (5000+), it comes from a cakephp query.

I would like to display it in a jqgrid.

I tried this way :

jquery:

```
$('#jqList').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    colNames:['Field 1', 'Field 2'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'field1',index:'field1', width:200},
        {name:'field1',index:'field1', width:300}
    ],
    pager: '#jqPager',
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        height: '100%',
});

var carsJson = <?php echo json_encode($cars) ?>;
for (data in carsJson) {
    jQuery('#jqList').addRowData(carsJson[data]['Enfant']['id'], carsJson[data]['Car']);
}
```

I can display my rows, but my page freeze for a few secondes and I don't have any page in my jqgrid :(

I would be glad to gather any usefull tips.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datatype `"json"` instead of `"local"` and an `url` which will deliver data. This way grid will load only the amount of lines necessary to show in UI and is much faster then loading all 5000 lines at the beginning.

```
url:'server.php?q=2',
datatype: "json",
```

Look here for an example: 
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html Loading Data/JSON data

Comment: I tried to make something like that, but my url return a 500 error despite I can access the url in a new page

Comment: I opened a more specific question there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565181/jqgrid-cant-display-json-data
thanks

Comment: As much as I would like to help you with error 500 but I am not experienced with php. I use IBM Domino as server and that works well. I'd suggest to add "php" as a tag to your new question and mention which kind of web server do you use. Thanks for voting up and accepting answer. Happy coding!