# jqgrid: can't display json data

Tags: json, jqgrid

I'm trying to display json data in a jqgrid and I don't get any row.

Here is my grid :

```
$('#jqList').jqGrid({
        url: '/my/url',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['field1', 'field2'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'field1',index:'field1', width:200},
        {name:'field2',index:'field2', width:300}
    ],
    pager: '#jqPager',
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
            id: 'id'
        }
});
```

I can access my url in my browser and it displays something like this :

```
    {"rows": [
        {"id": "3", "field1": "blabla", "field2": "blabla"},
        {"id": "10", "field1": "blabla", "field2": "blabla"},
        {"id": "4", "field1": "blabla", "field2": "blabla"},
        {"id": "8", "field1": "blabla", "field2": "blabla"}
    ]
}
```

But when I display my grid, I don't have any data as I said.
If I check the console, I have a 500 error on my url (with some params added to the url)

I hope I gave enough informations.

**edit**
firebug console says :

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/path/to/my/url?_search=false&nd=1373439192511&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc"
```

I'm using PHP on apache server

php code :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
foreach ($cars as $k => $v) {
    $tab['rows'][$k] = $v['Car'];
}
echo json_encode($tab);
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, can you edit the question with details about your 500 error (the message etc.)

Comment: I've added the firebug console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that jqGrid was waiting a url like that : path/to/my/json/url despite I gave `url : path/to/my/url`
on the development server... and `url : path/to/my/url` works fine on the beta server...

I don't really understand why, if the url was "wrong" why the error wasn't 404 ?

Anyway it's working fine now...

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the URL generated by jqGrid:

```
http://localhost/path/to/my/url?_search=false&nd=1373439192511&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Is causing some kind of error on the server side (I don't know which server side technology are you using but for example in case of ASP.NET this kind of response means that there was unhandled exception).

You have stated that the clean URL, which should look like this:

```
http://localhost/path/to/my/url
```

Is working properly. In that case you, if you don't need the parameters which jqGrid is adding you can try to work around the problem by telling jqGrid not to send them:

```
$('#jqList').jqGrid({
    url: '/my/url',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames:['field1', 'field2'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'field1',index:'field1', width:200},
        {name:'field2',index:'field2', width:300}
    ],
    pager: '#jqPager',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    prmNames: {
        page: null,
        rows: null,
        sort: null,
        order: null,
        search: null,
        nd: null
    },
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
        id: 'id'
    }
});
```

This is not a perfect solution (we still doesn't know why your server is generating internal error and how to solve that) but it might make your code work. If you want to address the server side problem we must know more about what is happening on the server.

Comment: thank you. I'm using php on apache server.
I tried your prmNames method, I still have the 500 error, but the url is now clear of any params.

Comment: @ThEBiShOp Then you need to debug and provide us with more informations regarding your server side code. The issue is there and there is nothing more we can do on client side. Check your Apache logs for starter.

Comment: in the apache error log, I have nothing relevant (last entry 2 hours ago on a missing favicon) and in the access log I have that :
`127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2013:11:21:59 +0200] "GET /my/url HTTP/1.1" 500 169`

Comment: @ThEBiShOp Well it means that Apache is seeing this this 500 as a response genrated by the application, you need to dig deeper in order to find the error raising place in PHP. This is a short artcile descibing configuration of PHP error log: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/

Comment: @tpeczek: JSON response from the server has `rows` as root. So one will need to change `root` definition of `jsonReader` to `root: "rows"` after the problem with 500 error will be solved on the server side.

Comment: thanks, my php error log is enabled but it's empty (I created a syntax error to make sure it's working, and the syntax error is logged).
I guess my 500 error is more an access error from jqgrid

Comment: @ThEBiShOp Well something on the server side must generate this error (it can't be generated on client side with JavaScript). Without any further informations I'm unable to help here.

Comment: @ThEBiShOp: 500 Internal Server Error means **any** error (typically an exception) in the server code. You don't provided any PHP code. One can't help you having the information: there are an error during executing of my PHP code, where is the error? One can't solve the problem having such information. The best way is **debugging** the code step by step in the debugger. If you know the line which produce the error then you can fix the bug.

Comment: maybe the problem is the mime type... when I access `http://localhost/path/to/my/url` in my browser, the type is text/html though I added `header('Content-type: application/json');` at the top of my file...
jqgrid is expecting application/json, maybe the problem is there...

Comment: @Oleg I've added the php code in the main post. It's really simple and don't give any error when I access the url in my browser directly

Comment: I don't understand why jqgrid give me a 500 error since I can access my url without any trouble... I would like to give more informations, but I don't know what to check or give...

Comment: @ThEBiShOp Once again, this is not jqGrid giving your 500 it is your server. We can't determine why without you actually debuging your server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get 500 errors it means that the url path is wrong for javascripts or mvc controllers.

First thing is first,

Your datamap, is it in the same file as your grid?  If it is then give it a name and reference that name in the url. If you are getting the data from a db, then you probably using a controller to get the data back and converting it to a json serializable object.  So the url should point to the location of that controller.